# Can't enable py-bt for gdb

Tags: python, gdb

I have downloaded and compiled Python 3.5 on a CentOS 6.5 machine. It works without problems. The problem is I have to use `gdb` to debug a subtle bug involving cpu overuse during my python program execution.

From official Python documentation about [gdb extension](https://docs.python.org/devguide/gdb.html), they says the only thing to do is to add

`add-auto-load-safe-path /path/to/dir/with/python-gdb.py`

to `~/.gdbinit`. I tested it with

```
gdb --args /path/to/python3.5/binary
(gdb) py-bt
```

but I get

```
Undefined command: "py-bt"
```

`gdb` is version 7.2 and have python support enabled.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found it! You must add `/PATH_TO_PYTHON_SRC/Tools/gdb` to `PYTHONPATH`, then in `gdb` you should be able to execute:

```
python import libpython
```

Source: https://web.archive.org/web/20141105062553/http://sumitkgaur.wordpress.com/2014/05/13/python-debugging/

Answer (score 28):

Basing on blog post by [Debugging of CPython processes with gdb](http://podoliaka.org/2016/04/10/debugging-cpython-gdb/)
One more way to resolve the issue is to source `python3.5-gdb.py` file.
Run command `info auto-load` to check that files are loaded (if so)
and if not -- load it manually:
`source /usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/bin/python3.5-gdb.py`
(! path may be different).

Then `py-bt` should work!

EDITED: changed py version

Comment: How do you find out where the gdb.py file is?

Comment: You can try this command: `locate *-gdb.py | grep gdb/auto-load/usr/bin`

Comment: I think you have to do `sudo apt-get install python3-dbg` first.

Answer (score 6):

gdb auto-loads gdb CLI (or Python or Scheme) scripts by looking through the directory trees rooted at the directories in your [scripts-directory](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/objfile_002dgdbdotext-file.html#set%20auto%2dload%20scripts%2ddirectory) search path. For every executable or shared object that's loaded, gdb looks for scripts named `objfile-gdb.gdb` (or `objfile-gdb.py` or `objfile-gdb.scm`).

One way to auto-load the gdb extensions for `python` is to place that `python-gdb.py` file you downloaded to be under one of the directories in your scripts-directory path. For instance, the `python2.7-dbg` package on Ubuntu installs these files:

```
-rwxr-xr-x /usr/lib/debug/usr/bin/python2.7-gdb.py
lrwxrwxrwx /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0-gdb.py -> ../bin/python2.7-gdb.py
```

Here's a gdb session that shows how the `python2.7-gdb.py` script is auto-loaded when I start to debug the `/usr/bin/python` executable:

```
(gdb) show auto-load scripts-directory
List of directories from which to load auto-loaded scripts is $debugdir:$datadir/auto-load.
(gdb) set debug auto-load
(gdb) file /usr/bin/python
Reading symbols from /usr/bin/python...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug//usr/bin/python2.7...done.
auto-load: Attempted file "/usr/lib/debug/usr/bin/python2.7-gdb.gdb" does not exist.
auto-load: Expanded $-variables to "/usr/lib/debug:/usr/share/gdb/auto-load".
auto-load: Searching 'set auto-load scripts-directory' path "$debugdir:$datadir/auto-load".
auto-load: Attempted file "/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib/debug/usr/bin/python2.7-gdb.gdb" does not exist.
auto-load: Attempted file "/usr/lib/debug/usr/bin/python2.7-gdb.py" exists.
auto-load: Loading python script "/usr/lib/debug/usr/bin/python2.7-gdb.py" by extension for objfile "/usr/lib/debug/usr/bin/python2.7".
```

Comment: I added `python-gdb.py` to `/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib/python3/` without success.

Comment: @MarcoSulla Can you show what `set debug auto-load` followed by  `file /path/to/your/python` produces as output?

Comment: Nothing. Now I'm doing other tests, so I can't reproduce, sorry. It seems that adding `add-auto-load-safe-path /PATH/TO/PYTHON/BUILDDIR/python-gdb.py` works, but I can't import libpython inside gdb.

Answer (score 2):

I've spent a ridiculous amount of time getting this working on CentOS7 today. Just wanted to save/share how I finally made it work:

1. Follow https://wiki.python.org/moin/DebuggingWithGdb. in particular (assuming python3.6 is in use, otherwise the name of the last package can be different):

   ```
   sudo yum install yum-utils
   sudo debuginfo-install glibc
   sudo yum install gdb python3-debuginfo
   ```
2. After starting `gdb` and attaching it to the process you want to debug run:

   ```
   source /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib64/libpython3.6m.so.1.0-3.6.8-18.el7.x86_64.debug-gdb.py
   ```

   This is subject for version change obviously
3. Optionally add this to auto-load location as other answers suggest, I did not do this.

Answer (score 0):

If using Conda and/or CentOS with a version of Python newer than that available with yum package manager, simply build a copy of python and the `python-gdb.py` will present in the top build folder.  This file can then sourced in gdb.

```
$ tar xvf Python-3.8.17.tgz
$ cd Python-3.8.17
$ ./configure
$ make
$ conda activate myenv
$ gdb python -p 12345
(gdb) source ~/Python-3.8.17/python-gdb.py
(gdb) py-list
 693
 694    def Session_createHelper(parameters, eventHandlerFunc, dispatcher):
 695        return _internals.Session_createHelper(parameters, eventHandlerFunc, dispatcher)
```